# V-categories enriched in a monoidal V-category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

In an email to the [categories mailing list](https://www.mta.ca/%7Ecat-dist/) dated 21 August 2003, Street [writes](https://github.com/punkdit/categories/blob/master/www.mta.ca/cat-dist/archive/2003/03-8#L705-L716):

> 2. Max reminded me of his old result (not in the LaJolla Proceedings,
>    but known soon after) that a monoidal V-category is none other than a
>    monoidal category W with a "normal" monoidal functor W --> V.
>    (Normal here means that the unit is preserved.) I think this was
>    mentioned by Max somewhere in the literature but I cannot remember
>    where; possibly SLNM420. The good thing about it is that V-categories
>    enriched in the monoidal V-category W turn out to be mere
>    W-categories.  An example is the monoidal category W = DGAb of chain
>    complexes of abelian groups; it can be regarded as a monoidal
>    additive category (that is, enriched in abelian groups V = Ab) or as
>    a mere monoidal category; categories enriched in the latter are
>    automatically additive.

Is there a reference in the literature for the definition of "$\mathcal V$-category enriched in a monoidal $\mathcal V$-category $\mathcal W$" and proof that it reduces in the manner described?

(Presumably "SLNM420" is the [Proceedings of the Sydney Category Theory Seminar 1972/1973](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0063096), but I could not find a result like this there.)

Comment: I notice, Part II of Lucyshyn-Wright's [Relative symmetric monoidal closed categories I: Autoenrichment and change of base](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02220) is supposed to contain this result, but it has not yet appeared.